# What would see an observer while moving inside a curved space?

Tags: curvature, spacetime-dimensions, space

What would see an observer while moving inside a curved space? I am really having big problems to visualise a motion inside a curved 3D space so I posted this two pictures to ask if it is a possibility of describing a motion inside a curved space. (My opinion is that the universe should be finite...) So should a person while moving from one pole to the other see objects on the equator not moving but just rotating so when the person reaches the other pole he can just see the hemispheres of all objects at the equator that were previously hidden to him at the start of the journey as he is in reality orbiting that objects? Eventually moving still he will reach again the first pole and the objects on the equator should show the starting hemispheres to the observer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a lot to unpack here, but one comment is that there is no "pole and equator", per se, for a 3-dimensional sphere. For a normal 2d sphere, if you pick two axes to form a plane, and project the sphere into this plane, you have lost one axis. The intersection of a line through the center, perpendicular to the plane you've chosen (parallel to the "projected axis"), will intersect the sphere at two points, these are the poles. For a 3-d sphere, if you choose two axes to form a plane, there are *two* axes remaining, so the analog of the poles is a *curve* (circle) intersecting the sphere.

Comment: For a curvature with spherical symmetry, it looks just like the world you're used to seeing, with a gravitational force in the direction of the local center of curvature.